# Ask and then answer one's own question on AskUbuntu?

Tags: discussion

I ask this question with the idea that this may be a way to pass along experience with configuring an ubuntu system.
  I have recently gone through a process and think that if I can properly ask and then answer a question, it may be helpful to others on AskUbuntu dealing with a similar situation. I would of course expect input from others and that would be most welcome. So perhaps, properly handled, discussion and other ideas
would be promoted, too.

Comment: Yes sure see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: It's encouraged: see [Can I answer my own question?](https://askubuntu.com/help/self-answer) in the [Help Center](https://askubuntu.com/help)

Comment: Thanks to all who replied. The links were very helpful.